# CakePHP Model generation Using Console

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to generate model using console in cakePHP.but getting an fatal error "class connection manager not found in model.php".please help me out to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of cake there was some changes that broke my setup. Changing `'port' => ''` to `'port' => null` fixed this. Might not be the issue, but it was giving me a whole lot of DB errors.